# Check existence of unknown field in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have this data from a MongoDB database, i want to return all the objects from the array "Books" and how to query for a specific book inside this array ?

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5b193757fb6fc05a6fe42330"
  },
  "Books": [
    {
      "Me Talk Pretty One Day ": {
        "_id": 312
      }
    },
    {
      "One Hundred Years of Solitude ": {
        "_id": 123
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to return specific book or whole array? please post your sample output

Comment: Both of them, i'll post the sample as soon as i can

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Comment: I had to use another type of query, it seems that placing the query as find( query, projection ) doesn't work anymore, i had to do find(query).project(projection)

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to answer, i don't usually do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrive specific book from the array you can try this

```
db.collection.find({
  Books: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "Me Talk Pretty One Day": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  Books: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "Me Talk Pretty One Day": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```